# Use of undeclared identifier DISPATCH_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_PRIORITY_DEFAULT), 0), ^{
                [self showSpinner];
            });
```

shows error "Use of undeclared identifier DISPATCH_PRIORITY_DEFAULT"

What do I need to import? Or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT instead of DISPATCH_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

No need to import any thing.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question. I got the dispatch code with the DISPATCH_PRIORITY_DEFAULT and didn't know what to do to make it work...